# CORS Error in Angular BotDetect with ASP.NET WebApi2 backend

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-web-api2, botdetect

I use Botdetect in angular 8 project and ASPNET WebApi2 Backend.

but this error

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:29739/simple-captcha-endpoint.ashx?get=html&c=yourFirstCaptchaStyle' from origin 'http://localhost:4500' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

I use EnableCors

```
 config.EnableCors();
        config.EnableCors(new EnableCorsAttribute("*", "*", "*")
        {
            SupportsCredentials = true,

        });
```

and added botdetect.xml file

```
<captchaEndpoint>
 <accessControlAllowOriginHeaderEnabled>true</accessControlAllowOriginHeaderEnabled>
 <accessControlAllowOriginHeaderValue>http://localhost:4500</accessControlAllowOriginHeaderValue>
</captchaEndpoint>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you work on local application, you can just install [extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-cors-access-control/lhobafahddgcelffkeicbaginigeejlf?hl=en).

If you want a real solution you have to add a proxy config, please check this [link](https://medium.com/better-programming/setup-a-proxy-for-api-calls-for-your-angular-cli-app-6566c02a8c4d)

This happens becuase your front and back have not the same URL and port, it's a cross-domain request.

Comment: I Use  config.EnableCors();  For CORS , But Only for botdetec occurred CORS error

Comment: I'm having exactly the same issue.

Comment: Do you still have the issue? if resolved can you tell how did you resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

Create a chrome shortcut
then open properties and add
--disable-web-security --disable-gpu --user-data-dir=~/chromeTemp
after "C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"